# Can somebody help me explain the results on how it come up with the values in column b_seq_number and b_changed_date?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I have this SQL code:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b."Seq_Number" AS b_Seq_Number,
    b."Changed_Date" AS b_Changed_Date
FROM
    src a
LEFT JOIN 
    src b ON a."Seq_Number" = b."Seq_Number" - 1
```

The output is:

[image]

I don't understand why the values in 'b_seq_number' and 'b_changed_date' is like that, when the join is using '-1' on the Seq_number

I am expecting row 1 would have an output of 0, and row 2 would have an output of 1 since it is subtracting by 1, right? But why in the world is it adding 1 ?

Can someone help explain the logic?

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected here.  You are doing a self join, and each matching record is being brought into alignment with the record having a sequence one earlier.

Comment: Your selected values do not add or subtract anything - they just display values from corresponding rows. Your joining condition states that a is joined with b-1 - in other words, if a=1, then b-1=a=1 => b=a+1=2.

Comment: Put the two tables (actually the same table, twice) side by side. Adjust the right table one row upwards. (And skip its first row, since it's a LEFT JOIN, not a FULL OUTER JOIN.)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table src (Seq_Number integer);

insert into src (Seq_Number) values (1);
insert into src (Seq_Number) values (2);
insert into src (Seq_Number) values (3);
insert into src (Seq_Number) values (4);
insert into src (Seq_Number) values (5);
insert into src (Seq_Number) values (6);


SELECT a.*,
       b.Seq_Number AS b_Seq_Number
    FROM src a LEFT JOIN src b
    ON a.Seq_Number = b.Seq_Number - 1;

 seq_number | b_seq_number 
------------+--------------
          1 |            2
          2 |            3
          3 |            4
          4 |            5
          5 |            6
          6 |         NULL
```

You're not decrementing b.Seq_Number, you're telling that a.Seq_Number must always be b.Seq_Number minus 1.

You're doing **a LEFT JOIN** which basically means "keep all rows from the left table, even if there is no corresponding data in the right table". It does NOT mean "keep all rows from the right table".

So your database returns you all rows of the left table that could match a row in the right table and checking that a.Seq_Number is always = b.Seq_Number - 1 **when there is a corresponding row in b**.

**No row in A match when B.seq_number is 1**, so the line in B where B.seq_number is 1 is not part of the result set.